# Any ways to clear the stretching of projection from view?

Tags: texturing, uv

I applied a texture to an object via projection from view. But there are stretches occurring at the boundaries. I tried texture paint to clone but failed. Is there any method to clear that stretching?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you don't want any stretching you need to choose another way than unwrap > Project from View I guess?

Comment: In this case it seems just moving the edge of UV map can unstretch: https://i.imgur.com/vMGdYvf.gif

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a proper unwrap, you can easily apply surface textures with a setup like this:

[image]

When you raise the *Blend* value, you'll see the seams start to blur and disappear.